# 3d chart for Highcharts with legends

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts for my website. I need legends support with 3d effect. But am unable to get 3d effect with "chart.options3d.enabled: true" and "plotOptions.pie.depth: ´numeric value´". Please suggest

Comment: are you setting alpha beta as well?

Comment: The legend is supported in charts 3d, so recreate your example with unworking elements.

Answer (score 0):

use alpha beta as well in config, without those it won't render as 3d, see  [fiddle created for you](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/an62r8k5/1/)

```
 options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 45,
            beta: 0
        }
```

for legends use showInLegend: true
also check highchart's 3D js in included or not [Highcharts 3D js](http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.src.js)